# Reuse variable in EOF bash script

Tags: bash, variables, eof

I have a script doing something like this:

```
var1=""
ssh xxx@yyy<<'EOF'
[...]
var2=`result of bash command`
echo $var2 #print what I need
var1=$var2 #is there a way to pass var2 into global var1 variable ?
EOF

echo $var1  # the need is to display the value of var2 created in EOF block
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How can this happen, the  commands inside here-doc are run in a shell on a remote server and `var1` is defined in the shell on your local machine

Comment: note:  if I remote the '' on EOF, the var2 is no longer available inside the block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, an executed command has three paths of delivering information:

1. By stating an exit code.
2. By making output.
3. By creating files.

It is *not* possible to change a (environment) variable of the parent process.  This is true for all child processes, and your `ssh` process is no exemption.

I would not rely on `ssh` to pass the exit code of the remote process, though (because even if it works in current implementations, this is brittle; `ssh` could also want to state its own success or failure with its exit code, not the remote process's).

Using files also seems inappropriate because the remote process will probably have a different file system (but if the remote and the local machine share an NFS for instance, this could be an option).

So I suggest using the output of the remote process for delivering information.  You could achieve this like this:

```
var1=$(ssh xxx@yyy<<'EOF'
[...]
var2=$(result of bash command)
echo "$var2" 1>&2 # to stderr, so it's not part of the captured output
                  # and instead shown on the terminal
echo "$var2"      # to stdout, so it's part of the captured output
EOF
)

echo "$var1"
```

Comment: Hi Alfe, sorry, my mistakes, but it seems not working as expected : 
output is like this :\n
    ./file.bash: rowxx : warning :« here-document » on line 32 delimited by end of file (instead of « EOF »)\n
    value of $var2 with assignation 1>&2\n 
    value of $var1 (begins with "Linux xxxx ... The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.\n
[...], but without any value of $var2\n
value of $var2 without assignation (just before the EOF)

Comment: Alfer, after some test, here how I found a workaround :
echo $var2
EOF)
var3=`echo "$var1" | tail -n 1`

regards.
echo "Et voila le fichier : $bkp_file"